# How to optimize this call to a string of static and dynamic strings? (JavaScript/Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, dynamic

I have this snippet of code which I simplified for the sake of this question:

```
//var a is generated once at runtime
//from an array of strings
//and an array of functions
var a = [ 
            "Start ",
            function(){return "middle ";}, //returns dynamic data
            "end"
        ],
    c = "";

//this for-loop represents a call
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    var d = typeof a[i] === 'function' ? a[i]() : a[i];
    c = c.concat(d);
}
console.log(c);
```

Now first question: Is my call (the for loop) less or more optimal than say...

```
var call = a[0]+a[1]()+a[2];
```

...where call was created at runtime somehow?

Conditional question: If the latter call is the more optimal approach then how would I go about generating this optimal call variable/object/function?

Final conditional question: If you can't figure out what I'm asking in my last question, ignore it. Instead, please tell me if my code is able to be further optimized and how?!

Edit: I went ahead and benchmarked my code by running 24M calls and the call variable is about 10% faster from my estimations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though correct, and fine in terms of performance, this code doesn't feel right to me. What I'd do would be:

```
var a = [ 
  "Start ",
  function(){return "middle ";}, //returns dynamic data
   "end"
];

var c = a.map(function(item) {
  return typeof item === 'function' ? item() : item;
}).join('');

console.log(c);
```

This seems better to me than appending to your string in each `for` iteration.

Comment: Nice terse code. I completely forgot about map() functionality in JS. Thanks!

Comment: The question is tagged with `node.js`, so I assume that the JavaScript code is meant to be used server-side. Node.JS is perfectly compatible with this feature, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Pierre: Yeah, I just realized and came to delete the comment...but not before you saw it! :-)

Comment: @Pierre Just ran the same benchmark against you map() implementation. It's actually the fastest by a margin of 5% :)

Comment: @user1418268: Glad to hear it. I knew that string concatenation should be avoided whenever possible, but I wouldn't have bet a penny on this result. =)

Answer (score 0):

The main answer here is: The `for` loop isn't going to introduce any kind of performance penalty you'll ever notice.

But:

If `a` is generated at runtime, you must have something, somewhere generating it. If so, rather than an array, why not just generate a function directly?

```
var acall = function() {
  return "Start, " + dynamic() + "end";
};
```

or

```
var acall = function() {
  return "Start, " + (function() {
    return "middle ";
  })() + "end";
};
```

The crux, really, is ***how*** `a` is generated at runtime. You can usually generate functions at runtime without resorting to `eval` or its cousin `new Function`...

Comment: Well, `var a` is really just a merge of two arrays. One containing strings and another containing functions that return strings. I don't know the contents of the two arrays in advance. Can you please elaborate on how I could create a function out of these?

Comment: @user1418268: Can you elaborate on how the arrays are created?

Comment: I have a text file with some custom markup and a JS file. The static strings are created from the text file, split depending on the markup. The functions are simply loaded from the JS file by referring to the text file for their identifier.

Comment: @user1418268: Then I think what you have is the best thing.

Comment: I'll actually go with Pierre's implementation because it's 5% faster for some reason. Thanks for the help!